# OK button in pop up window needs to be clicked after save button from initial window is selected in selenium for IE

Tags: selenium

I need to click an OK button inside a window that pops up after the Save button is clicked from the initial window.

What command should I use in selenium to get this going?

I am stuck in this.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("button")).click(); // This clicks the save button in the initial window
String savebuttonpopup= driver.getWindowHandle();   // Here I have used a String object which stores the dynamic value being generated by the application for the pop up window that display

System.out.println("Print Title========"+driver.switchTo().window(savebuttonpopup).getTitle()); 
// To cross-verify if I am present in the pop up window I try to display the title of the pop up here and it displays correctly.
```

But the OK button which is present in the pop up window is not clicked somehow with any commands I tried.

Last, but not the least, I need to do this in IE.

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of the pop-up window that you are getting in [imgur](http://www.imgur.com/) and the share the link here ? It will be easier to determine what type of pop-up are you encountering, actually and hence help us in sorting this one out. :)

Answer (score 0):

If its a confirmation pop-up only then use

`driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`

Try with JavascriptExecutor

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("Enter OK button Xpath"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Shubham but its just not a confirmation pop up. There is a drop down field and a text box as well..But those fields need not be used. I just need the OK button of the pop up window to be clicked. I doubt its a frame inside the pop up window. Though I have tried the command that you mentioned above but it did not help

Comment: I have edited my post . please try with JavascriptExecutor . It should work.. replace your xpath in code

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

And it is better to add some waiting periode before switching to the pop up